# How to Remote Control Android smartphone, if not in same subnet

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, linux, remote-control, remote-access, networking

I'd like to "Remote Control" my Android 2.3.x (Oxygen 2.3.2 ROM) from my PC. I know that there are VNC servers available *(previously available via https://market.android.com/details?id=org.onaips.vnc)* and also apps like Remote Web Desktop *(previously available via https://market.android.com/details?id=net.xdevelop.rm)*.

This works fine, but only if the mobile phone and the "controlling PC" are in the same subnet, or if traffic from PC -> mobile phone is routable.

At work, this isn't the case for me… :/ **The WiFi devices are in a separate subnet, and the *office network devices cannot reach the WiFi devices*.** That's done on purpose and is to be accepted as an unchangeable fact (at least for the time being).

If the mobile phone were a normal PC/Mac/Linux system, I'd install TeamViewer on it and be all set. But there's no *TeamViewer server for Android*, is there?

Well, what are your suggestions? How can one remote control the Android smartphone from a Linux (or any…) system, if the PC doesn't "see" the mobile phone?

I do have USB and Bluetooth available, if this helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is rooted (which I'm assuming it is since you're running Oxygen), you could try [androidscreencast](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/). It allows you to interact with a rooted phone over USB using mouse and keyboard. It's not the fastest solution, but then again, neither is a VNC server and the like.

There's a fairly decent walkthrough on how to set everything up on [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42491/how-to-remote-view-and-control-your-android-phone/). You'll also need to have `adb` in order to use androidscreencast (the Android SDK is one way; there's probably also some places you can directly download the necessary binaries).

Comment: Hi. That's indeed a cool solution! I had a look on the Market in the mean time, and found the [Webkey App](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.webkey). Webkey allows to "proxy" all the stuff thru the developers hosting thing. Works somewhat "fast", but then you've got to trust the dev. OTOH: you anyway have to trust the dev, so… Anyway, the more solutions, the better, and so I'm really thankful for your idea!